# How to send mail with ruby over smtp with ssl (not with rails, no TLS for gmail)

Tags: ruby, ssl, smtp

All I want is to send emails from my ruby scripts, over SMTP using SSL.

I only find examples of doing it from Rails, or for Gmail with TLS.

I found people talking about SMTPS support with ruby 1.8.5, but the [libdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/classes/Net/SMTP.html) doesn't mention it.

Anyone with an example of sending mail over SMTP with SSL, on port 465?

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
```

Answer (score 12):

I solve this issue with this configuration below :

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'mail.domain.com',
    :port                 => '465',
    :domain               => 'yourdomain.com',
    :user_name            => 'email@yourdomain.com',
    :password             => 'yourpassword',
    :authentication       => :login,
    :ssl                  => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none' #Use this because ssl is activated but we have no certificate installed. So clients need to confirm to use the untrusted url.
}
```

It works very well for me.

Comment: Was fighting with gitlab/mail notifications - :ssl => true worked for me.

Comment: the README.md doc(https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-emails-from-a-pop-server) for Mail Gem is really old, so `:enable_ssl => true` no longer works, instead use `:ssl => true`, what a pain 〒_〒

Answer (score 3):

How about pony ?
gem install pony.
http://github.com/adamwiggins/pony/tree/master
or I did not understand your question ?
 
I hope it help you.
Thanks
tknv/

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know about the [Net::SMTP standard library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/classes/Net/SMTP.html)

Regarding the SSL part, which doesn't seem to be supported out of the box, I found a couple of possible pointers:

- [Stephen Chu blog post](http://www.stephenchu.com/2006/06/how-to-use-gmail-smtp-server-to-send.html)
- [ActionMailer SSL setup example](http://ianli.com/site/HowTo/RailsApplicationStarter-SetupActionMailer) (ActionMailer uses Net::SMTP under the hood, AFIAK)

Comment: I already tried those examples, and work great with gmail, but I can't get them working with regular SMTP over SSL on my ISP accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The only interesting thing I've heard of in programmatic email recently is Lamson:  http://lamsonproject.org/

It's Python, not Ruby, but you can call Python from Ruby if you want to (here's one way: http://www.goto.info.waseda.ac.jp/~fukusima/ruby/python-e.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party open source command line program like mailsend (http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/mailsend/mailsend.html) to do your dirty work for you. Just pipe some output to it in the format it expects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use SSL instead of TLS you can monkey-patch Net::SMTP like this:

```
require "openssl"
require "net/smtp"

Net::SMTP.class_eval do

  def self.start( address, port = nil,
                  helo = 'localhost.localdomain',
                  user = nil, secret = nil, authtype = nil, use_tls = false,
                  use_ssl = false, &block) # :yield: smtp
    new(address, port).start(helo, user, secret, authtype, use_tls, use_ssl, &block)
  end

  def start( helo = 'localhost.localdomain',
             user = nil, secret = nil, authtype = nil, use_tls = false, use_ssl = false ) # :yield: smtp
    start_method = use_tls ? :do_tls_start : use_ssl ? :do_ssl_start : :do_start
    if block_given?
      begin
        send start_method, helo, user, secret, authtype
        return yield(self)
      ensure
        do_finish
      end
    else
      send start_method, helo, user, secret, authtype
      return self
    end
  end

  private

  def do_tls_start(helodomain, user, secret, authtype)
    raise IOError, 'SMTP session already started' if @started

    if VERSION == '1.8.6'
      check_auth_args user, secret, authtype if user or secret
    elsif VERSION == '1.8.7'
      check_auth_args user, secret
    end

    sock = timeout(@open_timeout) { TCPSocket.open(@address, @port) }
    @socket = Net::InternetMessageIO.new(sock)
    @socket.read_timeout = 60 #@read_timeout
    @socket.debug_output = STDERR #@debug_output

    check_response(critical { recv_response() })
    do_helo(helodomain)

    raise 'openssl library not installed' unless defined?(OpenSSL)
    starttls
    ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock)
    ssl.sync_close = true
    ssl.connect
    @socket = Net::InternetMessageIO.new(ssl)
    @socket.read_timeout = 60 #@read_timeout
    @socket.debug_output = STDERR #@debug_output
    do_helo(helodomain)

    authenticate user, secret, authtype if user
    @started = true
  ensure
    unless @started
      # authentication failed, cancel connection.
        @socket.close if not @started and @socket and not @socket.closed?
      @socket = nil
    end
  end

  def do_ssl_start(helodomain, user, secret, authtype)
    raise IOError, 'SMTP session already started' if @started

    if VERSION == '1.8.6'
      check_auth_args user, secret, authtype if user or secret
    elsif VERSION == '1.8.7'
      check_auth_args user, secret
    end

    sock = timeout(@open_timeout) { TCPSocket.open(@address, @port) }
    raise 'openssl library not installed' unless defined?(OpenSSL)
    ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock)
    ssl.sync_close = true
    ssl.connect
    @socket = Net::InternetMessageIO.new(ssl)
    @socket.read_timeout = 60 #@read_timeout
    @socket.debug_output = STDERR #@debug_output

    check_response(critical { recv_response() })
    do_helo(helodomain)

    do_helo(helodomain)

    authenticate user, secret, authtype if user
    @started = true
  ensure
    unless @started
      # authentication failed, cancel connection.
        @socket.close if not @started and @socket and not @socket.closed?
      @socket = nil
    end
  end

  def do_helo(helodomain)
     begin
      if @esmtp
        ehlo helodomain
      else
        helo helodomain
      end
    rescue Net::ProtocolError
      if @esmtp
        @esmtp = false
        @error_occured = false
        retry
      end
      raise
    end
  end

  def starttls
    getok('STARTTLS')
  end

  def quit
    begin
      getok('QUIT')
    rescue EOFError, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
    end
  end
end
```

See http://github.com/collectiveidea/action_mailer_optional_tls/blob/master/lib/smtp_tls.rb