# Ruby Mail, how to achieve SSL email

Tags: ruby, email

I have successfully sent email to a remote server using port their port 25 (non-secure) with this script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mail'

options = { :address              => "mail.domain.com",
            :port                 => 25,
            :domain               => 'mail.domain.com',
            :user_name            => 'somedude@domain.com',
            :password             => 'topsecret',
            :authentication       => 'login',
            :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
 Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end

 mail = Mail.new do
      from 'someotherdude@otherdomain.com'
        to 'somedude@domain.com'
   subject 'This is a test email'
      body File.read('body.txt')
 end

puts mail.to_s
mail.deliver!
```

What I need to do now is use their SSL port 466. When I try it, I get the normal output detailing the message, then it pauses for about 2 minutes and coughs up this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60:in `rbuf_fill': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:911:in `recv_response'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:554:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:921:in `critical'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:554:in `do_start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/mail-2.2.10/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:127:in `deliver!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/mail-2.2.10/lib/mail/message.rb:243:in `deliver!'
        from testmail.rb:30
```

I think this is because it cannot even begin the SSL authentication process. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm reading the network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb,  it doesn't look like it support Direct SSL.  TLS isn't them same, as the connection starts out Plain Text and then Switches to SSL on the starttls command.   Can you just use starttls on port 587?

pulling my comment up.

see

[How to send mail with ruby over smtp with ssl (not with rails, no TLS for gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708858/how-to-send-mail-with-ruby-over-smtp-with-ssl-not-with-rails-no-tls-for-gmail)

Which suggests that you can monkey patch Net::SMTP to do it..

Ok kinda found the issue and can patch around it, but so far this solution is yucky..  but it does work :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require "openssl"
require "net/smtp"
require "mail"

Net::SMTP.class_eval do

  def self.start( address, port = nil,
                  helo = 'localhost.localdomain',
                  user = nil, secret = nil, authtype = nil, use_tls = false,
                  use_ssl = true, &block) # :yield: smtp
    new(address, port).start(helo, user, secret, authtype, use_tls, use_ssl, &block)
  end

  def start( helo = 'localhost.localdomain',
             user = nil, secret = nil, authtype = nil, use_tls = false, use_ssl = true ) # :yield: smtp
    start_method = use_tls ? :do_tls_start : use_ssl ? :do_ssl_start : :do_start
    if block_given?
      begin
        send start_method, helo, user, secret, authtype
        return yield(self)
      ensure
        do_finish
      end
    else
      send start_method, helo, user, secret, authtype
      return self
    end
  end

  private

  def do_tls_start(helodomain, user, secret, authtype)
    raise IOError, 'SMTP session already started' if @started

    check_auth_args user, secret

    sock = timeout(@open_timeout) { TCPSocket.open(@address, @port) }
    @socket = Net::InternetMessageIO.new(sock)
    @socket.read_timeout = 60 #@read_timeout
    @socket.debug_output = STDERR #@debug_output

    check_response(critical { recv_response() })
    do_helo(helodomain)

    raise 'openssl library not installed' unless defined?(OpenSSL)
    starttls
    ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock)
    ssl.sync_close = true
    ssl.connect
    @socket = Net::InternetMessageIO.new(ssl)
    @socket.read_timeout = 60 #@read_timeout
    @socket.debug_output = STDERR #@debug_output
    do_helo(helodomain)

    authenticate user, secret, authtype if user
    @started = true
  ensure
    unless @started
      # authentication failed, cancel connection.
        @socket.close if not @started and @socket and not @socket.closed?
      @socket = nil
    end
  end

  def do_ssl_start(helodomain, user, secret, authtype)
    raise IOError, 'SMTP session already started' if @started

    check_auth_args user, secret

    sock = timeout(@open_timeout) { TCPSocket.open(@address, @port) }
    raise 'openssl library not installed' unless defined?(OpenSSL)
    ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(sock)
    ssl.sync_close = true
    ssl.connect
    @socket = Net::InternetMessageIO.new(ssl)
    @socket.read_timeout = 60 #@read_timeout
    @socket.debug_output = STDERR #@debug_output

    check_response(critical { recv_response() })
    do_helo(helodomain)

    do_helo(helodomain)

    authenticate user, secret, authtype if user
    @started = true
  ensure
    unless @started
      # authentication failed, cancel connection.
        @socket.close if not @started and @socket and not @socket.closed?
      @socket = nil
    end
  end

  def do_helo(helodomain)
     begin
      if @esmtp
        ehlo helodomain
      else
        helo helodomain
      end
    rescue Net::ProtocolError
      if @esmtp
        @esmtp = false
        @error_occured = false
        retry
      end
      raise
    end
  end

  def starttls
    getok('STARTTLS')
  end

  def quit
    begin
      getok('QUIT')
    rescue EOFError, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
    end
  end
end

options = {
  :address              => "mail.domain.net",
  :port                 => 466,
  :domain               => 'mail.domain.net',
  :user_name            => 'doon@domain.net',
  :password             => 'Secret!',
  :authentication       => 'login',
  :use_ssl => true  }

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end

mail = Mail.new do
  from 'doon@domain.net'
  to 'doon@someotherdomain.com'
  subject 'This is a test email'
  body File.read('body.txt')
end

puts mail.to_s
mail.deliver!
```

for some reason the use_ssl in the orig monkey patch doesn't make it in, and couple that with VERSION being undefined in Net::SMTP.    So I changed that out, and forced use_ssl to be true, and was able to send email..

Comment: We don't have any control over the 466 port assignment and port 587 isn't available

Comment: Hmm doesn't appear that Net::SMTP supports SSL out of the box, which mail uses.   Take a look here.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708858/how-to-send-mail-with-ruby-over-smtp-with-ssl-not-with-rails-no-tls-for-gmail   looks like you can monkey patch Net::SMTP to work..

Comment: I tried that, and it produces the exact same result unfortunately.

Comment: hmm. Well i not sure then... Perhaps you can proxy it locally. Is this for all outbound email?  if so they maybe run a mail server locally, and then set it to smart host via ssl?

Comment: perhaps I handled the monkey patch wrong. Can you tell me precisely where it goes? I pasted it after require 'mail'

Comment: Hmm I will see if I can implement it and figure out why it doesn't work, Quick hack and sniffing the traffic it looks like it is is ssl encrypted., will update my answer when I figure it out..

Comment: Whoa! You did it! I can't believe it! You rock! Thank you!

Comment: Well I am not 100% happy with the solution, but when I get some more time I will look into cleaning it up, and making it toggle able with mail.  A couple of puts statement, as well as setting Net::SMTP into debug mode, showed where it was blowing up. And it seemed like an interesting problem.

Comment: ok I've done some digging and see where in mail the settings are getting lost (network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb), but will take more tinkering/time than I have at the moment to make it cleaner.

Comment: Ok just be aware that as it stands, that monkey patch will not work with regular mail servers  as it basically forces the use of SSL all the time.. So if your app needs to talk to non SSL mail servers as well, you will need to adjust it. Could check to see if port == 46(5|6) and then go sslonly in that case. I'll update this if/when I get to cleaning it up

Comment: Amazing, I was in the same boat and needed ssl and not tls. This monkey patch works

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use port 465? That's the standard fallback port, not 466. You're likely timing out connecting to the wrong port.

Comment: No, the port was assigned by our service provider. Someone else actually suggested that too so we tried it also, but to no avail.

Comment: What happens when you "telnet mail.myserver.com 466"? Do you get a connection at all?

Comment: no. Tried 465 too. Just says "Connecting to mail.safetysend.com..."

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with your server. Talk to the sysadmin.

Comment: Works fine with Doon's solution above.